# Authenticate user with a unique temporary codewith IdentityServer4

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm planning to bring in IdentityServer4 as a security token service to an existing solution. We can authenticate users with username/password pairs which covers majority of use cases we have.

However, we have some scenarios where small number of users are authenticated using a code emailed (embedded in a link, like www.mysite.com/codeusers/{uniquetempcode}) to the user, and given access to a limited section of the site.

Another, even less used scenario is to authenticate user based on their IP.

What is the best way to handle this kind of scenarios with IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best way, but you can use Extension Grants for that:

> OAuth 2.0 defines standard grant types for the token endpoint, such as
>   password, authorization_code and refresh_token. Extension grants are a
>   way to add support for non-standard token issuance scenarios like
>   token translation, delegation, or custom credentials.

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html